# Как создать виртуальную функцию, которая должна быть обязательно переопределена во всех производных классах?

Tags: c++

Как создать виртуальную функцию, которая должна быть обязательно переопределена во всех производных классах?

Comment: Это невозможно сделать. Нет такого способа, который заставлял бы переопределять виртуальную функцию в производных классах. Ответ, который вы выделили как лучший, некорректный. Производный класс также не обязан переопределять чистую виртуальную функцию базового класса и в свою очередь может быть абстрактным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется  **pure virtual function**:

```
virtual void f() = 0;
```

Это делает класс абстрактным и указывает, что потомки должны переопределить метод, если требуется инстанцировать экземпляр потомка. Иначе производный класс также будет абстрактным.